# Visual Studio Directory Settings For Multiple Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 which contains multiple projects. All of those projects share a common directory for header files and library files. When I go to Tools->Directories it tells me this approach is deprecated and that there is a separate Directory properties for each project. Surely Microsoft don't expect me to now add these settings to each project individually. Is there not a top level property which all projects inherit and then this project specific property? Am I missing something or do I really need to do this per project now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use are called [PropertySheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

When used right they are very powerful, especially for large projects.

With these you can specify much more common things, than just only different directories.

Comment: Thanks. Still means adding the same property sheet to each project (100 of them) but better than the alternative.

Comment: In the Property Manager you can use SHIFT or CTRL to select more than one project, then add the same property sheet to all selected projects.